# How get grouping rows in PHP from EXCEL?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

How get grouping rows in PHP from EXCEL?

[image]

This code does not issue a groups:

```
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("bulat_price.xlsx");
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$worksheet->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$spreadsheet = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file); // load file
$objWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0); // select firts sheet

$i = 0;
$arrLevel = [];

foreach ($worksheet->getRowDimensions() as $rowDimension) {
    $i++;
    $arrLevel[$i]['level'] = $rowDimension->getOutlineLevel(); // get level
}
$highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'

foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {    
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(true);

    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        $arrLevel[$row->getRowIndex()]["excel"][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getValue(); // merge level and value
    }
}

var_dump($arrLevel);
```

We get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bARop.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set an outline group over a range of rows (or columns) by setting it for each row; and you can nest outline groups by setting the group level argument.

```
// Set outline levels
for ($row = 2; $row <= 10; ++$row) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getRowDimension($row)
            ->setOutlineLevel(1)
            ->setVisible(false)
            ->setCollapsed(true);
}

for ($row = 4; $row <= 9; ++$row) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getRowDimension($row)
            ->setOutlineLevel(2)
            ->setVisible(false)
            ->setCollapsed(true);
}
for ($row = 6; $row <= 8; ++$row) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getRowDimension($row)
            ->setOutlineLevel(3)
            ->setVisible(false)
            ->setCollapsed(true);
}
```